# Send data to server URL and read back responses

Tags: c#

I have a program that I have a text file full of raw data which I would like to send to a server. I have the URL of the server, and an Array which I have all the responses I need to send. I would like to send the responses then echo back what the server receives into a text box just to double check what's being sent is correct. Can anyone help point me in the right direction of how to approach my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var result = wc.UploadString(uri, data);
```

Comment: [This is more along my question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) Would you mind offering a little explanation as to what your two lines of code are doing. I don't think two lines of code can quite accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfgang's answer looks so simple I am embarrassed to post the link to the [TCP Client Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256822/tcp-client-connection), but there it is if you want to see the hard way to do it.