# Sockets and listeners

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a client who uses tcp sockets to send and receive messages.
They gave us a destination IP and port.Just to get a feel of this, I started out with a small console application both client, server. I used my IP and port. Started the server. Then sent some string through the client. I was able to see it on the server console. 
This program only establishes a one way connection client->server. 
How do I accomplish a two way? 
Do I need to implement a tcp listener?

```
Server: 
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
             sck.Bind(localEndpoint);
            sck.Listen(100);

            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
            Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
            }
            string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            Console.WriteLine(strData);
            Console.Read();
            sck.Close();
            accepted.Close();



       }
Client: 
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
         //   IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("68.109.249.167"), 35520);
            try
            {
                sck.Connect(localEndpoint);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("unable to connect to remote endpoint");
                Main(args);
            }
            Console.Write("Enter Text");
                string text=Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] data= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

            sck.Send(data);
            Console.Write("Data Sent!\r\n");
            Console.Write("Presee any key to continue");
            Console.Read();
            sck.Close();
        }
```

So now these demo client, server are able to communicate well.

In reality, Where does a listener come into play? We establish a connection and send some request.   `sck.Listen(100);`places the socket in a listening state.
Will they be sending the response on the same port..Do I need to use a Tcplistener class?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. 
Please suggest

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a question about this a few years back.

My code example was very much complete, so you might like taking a look at it:

[TCP Client Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1256822/153923)

Basically, your server will be the listener.

The client will send a message to your server like this:

```
private int sendUsingTcp(string location) {
  string result = string.Empty;
  try {
    using (var fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
      using (var client = new TcpClient(GetHostIP, CpAppDatabase.ServerPortNumber)) {
        byte[] riteBuf = new byte[client.SendBufferSize];
        byte[] readBuf = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        using (var ns = client.GetStream()) {
          if (ns.CanRead && ns.CanWrite) {
            int len;
            string AOK = string.Empty;
            do {
              len = fs.Read(riteBuf, 0, riteBuf.Length);
              ns.Write(riteBuf, 0, len);
              int nsRsvp = ns.Read(readBuf, 0, readBuf.Length);
              AOK = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuf, 0, nsRsvp);
            } while ((len == riteBuf.Length) && (-1 < AOK.IndexOf("AOK")));
            result = AOK;
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Message Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand, 0);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Basically, right after I do a write: `ns.Write(riteBuf, 0, len);`

I do a read: `ns.Read(readBuf, 0, readBuf.Length);`

For there to be something to read, the code on your server has to be configured to send a response after it receives data.

My server was configured like this:

```
using (var ns = client.GetStream()) {
  if (ns.CanRead && ns.CanWrite) {
    int len;
    byte[] AOK = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AOK");
    using (var fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
      do {
        len = ns.Read(buf, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
        ns.Write(AOK, 0, AOK.Length);
      } while ((0 < len) && ns.DataAvailable);
    }
    byte[] okBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message Received on Server");
    ns.Write(okBuf, 0, okBuf.Length);
  }
}
```

I hope that is clear.

**UPDATE:**

If you need a particular message returned, that could be done but I don't know where you'd need to add in your data.

```
private const string FMT_REPLY = 
  "POST_/OKMMISPOS_HTTP/5.1 " +
  "Content-Length:_521 ISA*00*" +
  "__________*00*" +
  "__________*ZZ*500000330" +
  "______*ZZ*731476619" +
  "______*090303*1414*U*004";
```

That's a nasty looking message, by the way.

Using the constant defined above, you would modify the code to be:

```
    byte[] AOK = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FMT_REPLY);
    using (var fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
      do {
        len = ns.Read(buf, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
        ns.Write(AOK, 0, AOK.Length);
      } while ((0 < len) && ns.DataAvailable);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @jp2code: Where are you exactly sending the message to the server and where is the listening done? I will get up to speed with it probably in the next 2 hrs..:)

Comment: Updated with the client that reads a response and the server that sends that response. You can, of course, edit those responses to be anything you want. I chose the short text `AOK`.

Comment: How would I also add a httpheader to the outgoing message. Can I just do a simple append to the actual message. They are expecting something like this POST_/OKMMISPOS_HTTP/5.1
Content-Length:_521
 
ISA*00*__________*00*__________*ZZ*500000330______*ZZ*731476619______*090303*1414*U*004
...I have the second part in place. Didn't know what would be the best way to send a http header

Comment: Replace the part above that has `"AOK"` with your string. I think I'll have to edit the post to show that though...

Comment: How do I trace this outgoing TCp request. Fiddler doesn't seem to do it

Comment: [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/‎) might be able to do that, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a `TCPListener` class at all, you could simply use `Socket.Listen` for this purpose. I've pulled up some code I've written half a year ago or so (and is still being used):

```
            _listenerThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                // Set up our server socket and set it to reuse addresses.
                ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                ServerSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

                // Bind it to the local server.
                ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PortNumber));

                ServerSocket.Listen(MaxQueueLength);

                // Once we get an incoming connection, let the HandleClientConnection handle it further.
                ServerSocket.BeginAccept(HandleClientConnection, ServerSocket);
            });

            _listenerThread.Start();
```

In this specific case, I have a separate thread for my listener, and once a request comes in on my `ServerSocket` object, `HandleClientConnection` is called, which is basically the handshake between client and server.

To make sure that we continue to listen for new connections after we've accepted and registered the one coming in, I added the following to the `finally` block of `HandleClientConnection`:

```
            // Whatever happens, we want to make sure we start listening to incoming connections after handling the current one.
            ServerSocket.BeginAccept(HandleClientConnection, result.AsyncState);
```

What this does is essentially create a circle; whenever a new client connects, the server accepts it, creates a new `ClientConnection` object for it, and goes back to `BeginAccept` to listen for new clients.

I apply the exact same when it comes to handling messages from clients. There's an extremely useful piece of code on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/c-tcp-socket-server) which is what I based the above code off.